# Hide input field when advanced form is shown

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a form that contains a basic and advanced search fields.
The form toggles between basic and advanced with the following code:

```
// toggle
$(function() {
    $(".toggler").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find("span").toggle();
        $(".togglee").slideToggle();
    });

    //show adv div based on input value data 
    if ($("#Adv input[value!='']").length) {
        $('.toggler').click();
    }
});​
```

**I want to have one specific input field (lets name it place) to be hidden when the advanced form is open.**

What do I need to add in the jQuery code above without breaking anything that is in place that is shared across other files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside the toggler click event, can't you just do:

```
$("#place").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(".toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find("span").toggle();
    $(".togglee").slideToggle();
    //hide another item?
    $('#myOtherItem').toggle();

});
```

OR maybe like this:

```
$(".toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find("span").toggle();
    $(".togglee").slideToggle();
    //hide another item?
    if($(".togglee").is(":visible")){
    //code for when the togglee is shown
    }

});
```